# angular catch (and prevent) the click on the previous page button on a browser

Tags: angular, url

I use Angular 9,
In one of my component I use a few # in the url , but staying in the same routing-url.

think like :
http://myWebsite/compo1#phase1;  http://myWebsite/compo1#phase2;

I need to customise the behavior when the user click on the "previous" and "next" button of the browser.

so far I use:

```
@HostListener('window:popstate')
```

onPopState($event) {
updateUrl($event);
$event.preventDefault();
}

I can see the url being updated, but the event continue and it's still redirect to the page before the # ( http://myWebsite/home )

any idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you use angular router, then you can use its built in events. Have you tried?

```
router.events
  .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(e => /* do stuff */)
```

https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events